# Oracle Procedure error, but the SQL script runs fine on it's own

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Trying to implement a script that runs once a day with the below SQL script:

```
UPDATE WO_OPERATION wo_sub 
SET wo_sub.DUE_DATE = (SELECT wo_main.DUE_DATE 
                       FROM WO_OPERATION wo_main, WO_BOM wob 
                       WHERE wob.WOO_AUTO_KEY = wo_main.WOO_AUTO_KEY 
                         AND wob.WOB_AUTO_KEY = wo_sub.WOB_AUTO_KEY), 
    wo_sub.MANUAL_ECD = (SELECT wo_main.MANUAL_ECD 
                         FROM WO_OPERATION wo_main, WO_BOM wob 
                         WHERE wob.WOO_AUTO_KEY = wo_main.WOO_AUTO_KEY 
                           AND wob.WOB_AUTO_KEY = wo_sub.WOB_AUTO_KEY) 
WHERE wo_sub.WOB_AUTO_KEY > 0 
  AND wo_sub.OPEN_FLAG = 'T'
```

When the SQL script is ran manually in Interactive SQL, there are no errors.

Once the procedure is created and ran with "executer procedure", the following error occurs:

Error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 12: PLS-00905: object QCTL.UPDATE_SUBORDER_DUE_DATES is invalid
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>
> ORA-06512: at "QCTL.QC_SCHED_CUST_PKG", line 1632
> ORA-06512: at line 1
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 185
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 486
> ORA-06512: at "QCTL.QC_EMGR_PKG", line 1471
> ORA-06512: at line 2
>
> PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> Compile error at line 6, column 3
>
> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> Compile error at line 5, column 1

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure QCTL.UPDATE_SUBORDER_DUE_DATES as

Begin

UPDATE WO_OPERATION wo_sub SET wo_sub.DUE_DATE = (select wo_main.DUE_DATE from WO_OPERATION wo_main, WO_BOM wob where wob.WOO_AUTO_KEY = wo_main.WOO_AUTO_KEY and wob.WOB_AUTO_KEY = wo_sub.WOB_AUTO_KEY), wo_sub.MANUAL_ECD = (select wo_main.MANUAL_ECD from WO_OPERATION wo_main, WO_BOM wob where wob.WOO_AUTO_KEY = wo_main.WOO_AUTO_KEY and wob.WOB_AUTO_KEY = wo_sub.WOB_AUTO_KEY) where wo_sub.WOB_AUTO_KEY > 0 and wo_sub.OPEN_FLAG = 'T'

commit;

END;
```

This should apply the Due Date of a Work Order to all sub-woorkorders in a repair facility and i need to automate it to run at a certain time daily.

When the SQL script is ran manually, there are no errors...

Compiling the whole procedure brings to the following error:

> PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> Compile error at line 6, column 3
> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> Compile error at line 5, column 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [**Bad habits** to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there's an error in that procedure. Every statement has to be properly terminated with a semi-colon character. `UPDATE` isn't; hence the error.

Procedure was created, but **unsuccessfully** (you should have paid attention to message Oracle reported).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure QCTL.UPDATE_SUBORDER_DUE_DATES as

Begin

UPDATE WO_OPERATION wo_sub SET 
  wo_sub.DUE_DATE = (select wo_main.DUE_DATE 
                     from WO_OPERATION wo_main, WO_BOM wob 
                     where wob.WOO_AUTO_KEY = wo_main.WOO_AUTO_KEY 
                       and wob.WOB_AUTO_KEY = wo_sub.WOB_AUTO_KEY), 
  wo_sub.MANUAL_ECD = (select wo_main.MANUAL_ECD 
                       from WO_OPERATION wo_main, WO_BOM wob 
                       where wob.WOO_AUTO_KEY = wo_main.WOO_AUTO_KEY 
                         and wob.WOB_AUTO_KEY = wo_sub.WOB_AUTO_KEY) 
  where wo_sub.WOB_AUTO_KEY > 0 
    and wo_sub.OPEN_FLAG = 'T';
                              ^
commit;                       |
                 this semi-colon is missing
END;
/
```

---

**[EDIT]** after you commented that you got ORA-00933 error; in that case, you did something wrong because there's no such error in my code.

Here's a demo.

Sample tables (as you didn't post that info yourself; next time, provide as many info as possible so that we wouldn't have to guess):

```
SQL> create table wo_operation
  2    (due_date     date,
  3     woo_auto_key number,
  4     wob_auto_key number,
  5     open_flag    varchar2(1),
  6     manual_ecd   number);

Table created.

SQL> create table wo_bom
  2    (woo_auto_key number,
  3     wob_auto_key number);

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure update_suborder_due_dates as
  2  begin
  3    update wo_operation wo_sub set
  4    wo_sub.due_date = (select wo_main.due_date
  5                       from wo_operation wo_main, wo_bom wob
  6                       where wob.woo_auto_key = wo_main.woo_auto_key
  7                         and wob.wob_auto_key = wo_sub.wob_auto_key),
  8    wo_sub.manual_ecd = (select wo_main.manual_ecd
  9                         from wo_operation wo_main, wo_bom wob
 10                         where wob.woo_auto_key = wo_main.woo_auto_key
 11                           and wob.wob_auto_key = wo_sub.wob_auto_key)
 12    where wo_sub.wob_auto_key > 0
 13      and wo_sub.open_flag = 'T';
 14    commit;
 15  end;
 16  /

Procedure created.
```

Procedure **created**. No ORA-00933, no nothing. Re-check your own code.

Comment: nice catch but i am still getting the following error:PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Compile error at line 6, column 3
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Compile error at line 5, column 1

Comment: I took another look, and this time created complete demo which shows that there's no error in my code. I hope you didn't blindly copy-paste my code; an arrow - which points to error you made - should be removed (as well as text that explains it). Have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: I did clean up the arrow and the text but still getting the same error message.

Comment: As you see, I don't get any errors, which means that you did something different. Can't tell what unless you edit the original question and post your new code. If possible, do it as I did - copy/paste your SQL*Plus session.

Comment: Strangely, the whole thing miraculously worked in SQL Plus, but not in DBeaver. Thank you for your help.